# SqlMetal alternative for .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: .net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Is there any way to generate database models from existing database (sdf file) for .NET Compact Framework 2.0? Since it doesn't support LINQ I cannot use SqlMetal.

I'm looking for free for commercial use tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLBLGenPro (commercial) supports SQL Compact and .NET CF. You could also try http://orm.codeplex.com